# Efficient Design Pattern for multiple if conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there are a design pattern that is capable of efficiently managing multiple if conditions (50+) in Javascript?

**Update**

What I'm trying to do is to return of HTML tags for each and every defined tag when a certain parameter is passed. Therefore all elements should be defined.

for an example

```
if ("html"){
   return "<html>";
}
```

Likewise for all HTML elements.

Comment: Show us some code ! Otherwise, [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/switch) could be your answer :|

Comment: Why do you have those many conditions? Is there any pattern? Without a pattern, the answer is *No*.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @KapilaHettiarachchi Please post your actual code. What you posted is always true.

Comment: That is not my question. My question is is it okay to have 50 if conditions or is there a better way of handling it?

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, half my if statement code is making sure that stuff is defined before I test it for the actually condition I care about. In a somewhat lazy solution you can skip all that testing by using a try block. See:

```
try {
  // will only run if both objects exist AND obj1 is greater.
  if (obj1 > obj2) runCode();
}
catch(err) {
  // do nothing
}
```

To provide an even better answer I would need to know more about your problem, though. If you can expand your question with some code examples then I can expand my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the **switch statement**

```
    switch (expr) {
case 'val one':
    // execute some code
    break;
case 'val two':
    // execute some code
    break;
case 'val three':
    // execute some code
    break;

default:
    // if nothing is matched execute this code
}
```

make sure to put a **break** after every case otherwise all the cases will be executed

more on the topic [switch - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: The OP didn't state that his conditions were string comparisons on the same value.

Comment: @Bergi I know, the string, in this case, is just for illustrating purposes only.

Comment: My emphasis was on "the same value". It could have been `if (a == "a") … else if (b == "b") …`, where `switch` absolutely does not help.

Comment: @Laassari so is it fine to have 50+ switch cases?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your idea but feel free to edit the example if you have any better one

Comment: @KapilaHettiarachchi I've never been in a situation in which I needed something like that but if it's some weird case then I can't think of any better alternative